# HTTP response content length w gzip

Tags: python, stream, gzip, python-requests, content-length

I am making a get request using Python's requests library and streaming the contents into a file. I'd like to add a progress bar by setting the max value of the progress bar to resp.headers['content-length'] and iterating through the response using chunksize=1 byte (response.iter_content(chunk_size=1)). However, the content encoding of the response is gzip so the content-length refers to the compressed size.

using the following code:

```
resp = requests.get(...., stream=True)
count = 0
for x in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1):
  count += 1
```

i get: count=64 and resp.headers['content-length'] = 127.

What should I use as the max value of the progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Kenneth's clint and do it like this.
Or what you should do is set your progress bar's implementation to update starting from 127.

```
from clint.textui import progress
import requests


resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
total_length = int(resp.headers.get('content-length'))

for chunk in progress.bar(resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1), expected_size=(total_length / 1) + 1):
    pass
```

Comment: This doesn't address my issue where the resp.headers.get('content-length') = 127 which is not equal to the number of iterations (count=64). The progress bar library and implementation is irrelevant

Comment: According to requests internals, it automatically decodes gzip. The false content_length while iterating content is hard to debug.